# reading qr codes from mobile phone using shiny webapp

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny web app in which I want that user should be able to decode the barcode data by scanning it through his mobile phone.
I have tried to write a code using qrcode library but I don't know how to call the mobile camera for scanning.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: https://community.rstudio.com/t/use-webcam-through-r/3504/8

Comment: That link talks about access to the webcam from R, but I think that's the wrong approach since it won't be "R" talking to the webcam, it'll be javascript talking to the browser talking to the OS/webcam. I think the first step would be to find javascript libraries that provide easy (and _secure_!) access to the webcam in a way that the browser and user are familiar, and then you'd need to use normal R/shiny/javascript interaction methods to get at that data.

Answer (score 0):

Despite my efforts, I haven't been able to find a precise solution to my problem. However, I have devised an alternative solution that involves capturing and rendering the QR code image, as described below.

Below is the R code. Hope this will help others.

```
library(shiny)
library(quadrangle)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Webcam Capture"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("image","Upload QR", accept = c('image/png', 'image/jpeg'))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("qr_results")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=15*1024^2)
  results <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$image, {
    results(qr_scan(input$image$datapath)$values$value)
  })
  
  output$qr_results <- renderPrint({
    if (!is.null(results())) {
      results()
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```